# Atmospheric reentry drag and friction

Tags: orbital-mechanics, reentry, atmospheric-drag

What is the difference of air drag in ground level with let say moderate speeds like fast cars 200km/h to 400km/h with high speed vehicle reentry at high altitude where the air is so rarified.
Making more simple is: {Low speed ( up to 0.5 mach ) + ground level air pressure )} ****versus**** { High speed ( 6- 7 km/s + air density at Kármán line.

Answer (score 3):

Drag has a lot of more complex factors that would require some simulation to determine exact values, but the [simplification](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/drageq.html) that is often used shows drag increasing linearly with air density and with the square of velocity.

Density at the Karman line is 1/2,200,000 that of ground level, so an increase from 0.5 mach to 7 km/s will feel roughly $\frac{(7000/170)^2}{2200000}=0.00077$ times the amount of drag. So, the same object in LEO would feel less than 1 tenth of 1 percent of the drag of the same object speeding along the ground.

However, this is still a significant amount of drag and you'll find yourself falling out of orbit pretty quickly.